# Dynamically created table does not display correctly on reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am dynamically creating a table using JavaScript/jQuery/html from an Ajax call. The first time the table loads it displays correctly formatted. However, when I do a refresh/reload the formatting of the table is not correct. I have included Promise to try and fix it as per [How to Promisify an Ajax Call](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-promisify-an-ajax-call/)

Correct on first load:

[image]

After reload:

[image]

The abbreviated code is:

```
$('#refreshTableBtn').click(function(){
    //Re-display the exercise table
    
    exerciseFirstColumnDetails()
        .then((numExeDetails) => {
            console.log(numExeDetails)
            loadExerciseDetails(numExeDetails)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log()
        })
});

function exerciseFirstColumnDetails() {
    //Get Patient Exercise Details
    $('#exerciseTable tr').empty();
    
    var numExeDetails = 0;
    
    //Get the Patient's exercise headers
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "PatientExerciseHeadersListView",
            data : {
                ssAccRole : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccRole'),
                ssAccID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccID'),
                ssPatExeID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssPatExeID'),
            },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
    
            //Loading spinner
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
        })
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('Error getting Exercise details.');
            reject();
        })
        .done(function(responseJson1a) {
            dataType: "json";
            
            if (Object.keys(responseJson1a)[0] == "empty") {
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('No Exercise details.');
            }else {
                //Create first table column
                //Loop through the Execise details
                //Populate the variable number of exercise variables and keep count.
                $.each(responseJson1a, function() {
                    numExeDetails++;
                    var html = "";
                    html += "<tr id='ExerciseDetail"+numExeDetails+"'  name='" + this.edeId + "'>";
                    html += "<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col'>"+ this.edeType + " - " + this.edeUnit + "</td>"
                    html += "</tr>"
                    $(html).insertBefore($("#InsertSet"));
                });
                
            }
            resolve(numExeDetails);
        });
    });
};

function loadExerciseDetails(numExeDetails) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: "PatientExerciseDetailsListView",
        data : {
            ssAccRole : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccRole'),
            ssAccID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccID'),
            ssPatExeID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssPatExeID'),
            ssPatExeID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssPatExeID'),
            viewFrom : $("#viewFromDate").val(),
            viewTo : $("#viewToDate").val(),
        },
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,

        //Loading spinner
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loader').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
    })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('Error getting Exercise details.');
    })
    .done(function(responseJson1a) {
        dataType: "json";
        
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('');
        
        if (Object.keys(responseJson1a)[0] == "empty") {
            //Display an empty table for data entry 
            //Check if the date range includes today's date.
            if (moment($("#viewFromDate").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').isAfter(moment())
                    || moment($("#viewToDate").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment())){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('No Patient exercises in this date range.');
            }else {
                var today = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                var todayDay = moment(new Date()).format('ddd')
                //If the date range includes todays date then display an empty table for data entry             
                $("<th class='h1Colour'>Set 1</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));
                $("<th class='h1Colour'>Set 2</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));
                $("<th class='h1Colour'>Set 3</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));

                //Create three sets for each Exercise Detail
                for(let i = 1; i <= numExeDetails; i++) {
                    var ExerciseDetail = "ExerciseDetail" + i;
                    alert(ExerciseDetail);
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col exeSet'><input type='text' name='exeSet' data-set='1' value='' size='4'></td>").appendTo($('#'+ExerciseDetail));
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col exeSet'><input type='text' name='exeSet' data-set='2' value='' size='4'></td>").appendTo($('#'+ExerciseDetail));
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col exeSet'><input type='text' name='exeSet' data-set='3' value='' size='4'></td>").appendTo($('#'+ExerciseDetail));
                }
            }
        }else{
            //Display existing sets
        }
    }); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id='exerciseTable'>
    <tr id="tableHeadersSet">
        <!-- Place for Set row -->
    </tr>
    
    <tbody id="tableBody">
        <!-- Add each of the Exercise Details -->
                            
        
        <tr id="InsertSet">
            <!-- Place for Insert Set button -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think there should be anything outside the `tbody`. I haven't looked at the rest.

Comment: @wazz Sorry, what do you mean by this comment please?

Comment: The first row should be inside a `thead` tag. I don't know if it will affect your problem, but I think that's more correct. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody. "If you use <tbody>, you can't also have table rows (<tr> elements) which are direct children of the <table> but not included inside the <tbody>."

Comment: @wazz OK, I got what you are saying. I added the  thead tag, which as you say is more correct; however, this did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to move the population of the first column to where I do the input lines.

```
$('#refreshTableBtn').click(function(){
    //Re-display the exercise table
    exerciseFirstColumnDetails()
        .then(({numExeDetails, exercises}) => {
            console.log({numExeDetails, exercises})
            loadExerciseDetails({numExeDetails, exercises})
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error + " Error in exerciseOverview.js - call 'loadExerciseDetails' function");
        })
});

function exerciseFirstColumnDetails() {
    //Get Patient Exercise Details
    $('#exerciseTable tr').empty();
    
    var numExeDetails = 0;
    var exercises = []; 
    
    //Get the Patient's exercise headers
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "PatientExerciseHeadersListView",
            data : {
                ssAccRole : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccRole'),
                ssAccID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccID'),
                ssPatExeID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssPatExeID'),
            },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
    
            //Loading spinner
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').show();
            },
            complete: function(){
                $('#loader').hide();
            },
        })
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('Error getting Exercise details.');
            reject();
        })
        .done(function(responseJson1a) {
            dataType: "json";
            
            if (Object.keys(responseJson1a)[0] == "empty") {
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('No Exercise details.');
            }else {
    //          $("#chartDisp").show();
                
                //Create first table column
                $("<th class='h2Colour sticky-col' colspan='1'>Week</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersWeek"));
                
                $("<th class='bgColourWhite sticky-col' colspan='1'>Date</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersDate"));
                
                $("<th class='bgColourWhite sticky-col' colspan='1'>Day</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersDay"));
                
                $("<th colspan='1' class='tdNoBorder sticky-col'></th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSpace1"));
                
                $("<th class='tdNoBorder sticky-col'></th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));
                
                //Loop through the Execise details
                //Populate the variable number of exercise variables and keep count.
                $.each(responseJson1a, function() {
                    //Pass 'exercises' to the next funtion
                    exercises[numExeDetails] = this.edeType + " - " + this.edeUnit;
                    numExeDetails++;
                    var html = "";
                    html += "<tr id='ExerciseDetail"+numExeDetails+"'  name='" + this.edeId + "'>";
//                  html += "<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col'>"+ this.edeType + " - " + this.edeUnit + "</td>"
                    html += "</tr>"
                    $(html).insertBefore($("#InsertSet"));
                });
                
                $("<td class='tdNoBorder sticky-col' colspan='1'></td>").appendTo($("#InsertSet"));
            }
            resolve({numExeDetails, exercises});
        });
    });
};

function loadExerciseDetails({numExeDetails, exercises}) {
    
    $.ajax({
        url: "PatientExerciseDetailsListView",
        data : {
            ssAccRole : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccRole'),
            ssAccID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssAccID'),
            ssPatExeID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssPatExeID'),
            ssPatExeID : sessionStorage.getItem('ssPatExeID'),
            viewFrom : $("#viewFromDate").val(),
            viewTo : $("#viewToDate").val(),
        },
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,

        //Loading spinner
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loader').show();
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
    })
    .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('Error getting Exercise details.');
    })
    .done(function(responseJson1a) {
        dataType: "json";
        
        $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('');
        
        if (Object.keys(responseJson1a)[0] == "empty") {
            //Check if the date range includes today's date.
            if (moment($("#viewFromDate").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').isAfter(moment())
                    || moment($("#viewToDate").val(), 'DD/MM/YYYY').isBefore(moment())){
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse4').text('No Patient exercises in this date range.');
            }else {                     
                
                var today = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                var todayDay = moment(new Date()).format('ddd')
                //If the date range includes todays date then display an empty table for data entry
                $("<th class='h2Colour' colspan='3'>1</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersWeek"));
                
                $("<th class='h1Colour' colspan='3'>" + today + "</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersDate"));
                
                $("<th class='h1Colour' colspan='3'>" + todayDay +"</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersDay"));
                
                $("<th colspan='3' class='tdNoBorder'></th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSpace1"));
                
                $("<th class='h1Colour'>Set 1</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));
                $("<th class='h1Colour'>Set 2</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));
                $("<th class='h1Colour'>Set 3</th>").appendTo($("#tableHeadersSet"));

                //Create three sets for each Exercise Detail
                var exercisesIdx = 0;
                
                for(let i = 1; i <= numExeDetails; i++) {
                    var exerciseDetail = "ExerciseDetail" + i;
                    
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col'>"+ exercises[exercisesIdx] +"</td>").appendTo($('#'+exerciseDetail));
                    exercisesIdx++;
                    
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col exeSet'><input type='text' name='exeSet' data-set='1' value='' size='4'></td>").appendTo($('#'+exerciseDetail));
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col exeSet'><input type='text' name='exeSet' data-set='2' value='' size='4'></td>").appendTo($('#'+exerciseDetail));
                    $("<td class='bgColourWhiteBold sticky-col exeSet'><input type='text' name='exeSet' data-set='3' value='' size='4'></td>").appendTo($('#'+exerciseDetail));
                }
                
                $("<td class='tdNoBorder sticky-col' colspan='3'><input type='button' name='addSetBtn' class='btn btn-sm h2Colour' style='width:100%' value='Add Set'></td>").appendTo($("#InsertSet"));
            }
        }else{
            //Display existing sets
        }
    }); 
}
```